# Xamarin listView selects wrong item

Tags: listview, xamarin

I'm starting with xamarin.
I show a listview with all available language. The user clicks on one and can save it. Here's my code
XAML :

```
<ListView x:Name="LanguageList" 
           SelectionMode="Single"
           ItemSelected="OnSelected">
</ListView>
```

CS :

```
private async void SetListLanguage(bool init)
    {
        itemList = new ObservableCollection<string>();
        l = await TextToSpeech.GetLocalesAsync();
        foreach (var locale in l)
        {
            if (filter.Length == 0)
                itemList.Add(locale.Name);
            else if (locale.Name.Contains(filter))
                itemList.Add(locale.Name);
            if (init && locale.Name == "English")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Initiating with English");
                local = locale;
            }
        }
        LanguageList.ItemsSource = itemList;
    }

void OnSelected(object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        selectedName = e.SelectedItem as string;
        Console.WriteLine("Selected " + selectedName);
        foreach (var locale in l)
        {
            if (selectedName != "" && locale.Name == selectedName)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Registered locale for  " + selectedName);
                local = locale;
            }
        }
    }
```

When I click on any language, for example Chinese, it gives me this weird output.

```
Selected Chinese (Taiwan)
    Registered locale for  Chinese (Taiwan)
    02-25 16:01:09.938 I/mono-stdout(15514): Selected Chinese (Taiwan)
    02-25 16:01:09.938 I/mono-stdout(15514): Registered locale for  Chinese (Taiwan)
    Selected 
    02-25 16:01:09.943 I/mono-stdout(15514): Selected 
    Selected Korean (South Korea)
    Registered locale for  Korean (South Korea)02-25 16:01:09.949 I/mono-stdout(15514): Selected Korean (South Korea)
    02-25 16:01:09.949 I/mono-stdout(15514): Registered locale for  Korean (South Korea)
```

I tried removing Korean, it gives me the same thing with French. SO it has something to do with the fact that it's the first on the list, but I don't see why.

Comment: What is the actual problem?  It appears that you selected Chinese, then deselected Chinese, then selected Korean.  Is that correct?  The Android log contains a LOT of verbose information that you can typically ignore - is that what's throwing you off?

Comment: The problem is that i only selected Chinese. It selected Korean on its own. When i remove Korean it selects French instead. They are the 2 on top of the list

Comment: You could check the screenshot, i show the correct data in output window.

Answer (score 0):

The `Console.Writeline` cause that situation. You could use `Debug.Writeline` instead.

```
  private void OnSelected(object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var selectedName = e.SelectedItem as string;
        //Console.WriteLine("Selected " + selectedName);
        Debug.WriteLine("Selected " + selectedName);
        foreach (var locale in l)
        {
            if (selectedName != "" && locale.Name == selectedName)
            {
                //Console.WriteLine("Registered locale for  " + selectedName);
                Debug.WriteLine("Registered locale for  " + selectedName);
                //local = locale;
            }
        }
    }
```

[image]

Leave Console.WriteLine in console applications where it belongs, and use Debug.WriteLine everywhere else. Quote from the blog. https://www.kolls.net/blog/?p=120

Answer (score 0):

You can use MVVM pattern binding selected item of listview below is my code hope it will help you :

XAML code :

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding DataItems}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedData}" HasUnevenRows="True" SeparatorVisibility="None">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell>
                <Frame Margin="10" Padding="0">
                    <Label Text="{Binding .}" Margin="20"/>
                </Frame>
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

View Model code:

```
public class MainPageViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private static readonly HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

    private ObservableCollection<string> dataItems;
    public ObservableCollection<string> DataItems
    {
        get { return dataItems; }
        set
        {
            dataItems = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    private string selectedData;
    public string SelectedData
    {
        get { return selectedData; }
        set
        {
            selectedData = value;
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(selectedData))
            {
                Application.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Alert", selectedData, "Ok");
            }
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public MainPageViewModel()
    {
        GetData();
    }

    public async Task GetData()
    {

        DataItems = new ObservableCollection<string>() {"One","Two","Three","Four","Five" };

    }


    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

Thanks

Output : when you click on any item of list view it will display selected item in display alert.

[image]